# Porque se duplican estilos en la consola del navegador?

Tags: css3, consola, sass

alguien sabe porque en la consola (o inspector de elementos) del navegador (Firefox o Chorme) aparecen duplicados los estilos que tengo en sass?

GRACIAS

[image: (]

Comment: Es posible que los estés llamando dos veces, si importas hojas de estilo desde otras hojas de estilo puede pasar facilmente

Comment: Muchas gracias, no lo sabía

Comment: ¿Era ese el problema?

Comment: Hola, yo diría que si porque tengo una hoja principal en .sass y ahi se están importando otras hojas .sass